# How to interact with tkinter widgets if they were made in a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a fairly large code that takes a json file and displays it in a window in tkinter using the treeview widget. There are a lot of such data files and the user can choose which file to show on the screen.
But when switching tables, I need to delete the contents of the window. But this cannot be done, because the widget is inside the function and cannot be interacted with from the outside or with the help of other functions. Also, when you run this function again, the previous widget completely disappears from memory but remains in the window and prevents the other selected table from playing.

```
def show_data(all_data):
    
    columns = ('Name', "Calories","Proteins","fats","carbohydrates")
    
    tree = ttk.Treeview( columns=columns, show="headings")
    tree.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    tree.heading("Name", text="Имя", anchor=W)
    tree.heading("Calories", text="калории", anchor=W)
    tree.heading("Proteins", text="Белки", anchor=W)
    tree.heading("fats", text="Жиры", anchor=W)
    tree.heading("carbohydrates", text="Углеводы", anchor=W)


    tree.column("#1", stretch=NO, width=745)
    tree.column("#2", stretch=NO, width=80)
    tree.column("#3", stretch=NO, width=80)
    tree.column("#4", stretch=NO, width=80)
    tree.column("#5", stretch=NO, width=80)

    for product in all_data:
        tree.insert("", END, values=product)
```

I tryed to use frame widget, but the problem is the same. Interact with the widget is obtained only inside the function itself. But as I described above, when the function is restarted, the previous widget disappears and the exact same one appears in its place, but the previous widget remains in the window.

```
tree_amount = 0
def grid_data(all_data):
    
    global tree_amount
    if tree_amount == 1:
        frame.destroy()
        tree_amount = 0
    
    tree_amount += 1
    
    frame = ttk.Frame(relief=SOLID)
    frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    columns = ('Name', "Calories","Proteins","fats","carbohydrates")
    
    tree = ttk.Treeview(master=frame, columns=columns, show="headings")
    tree.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    tree.heading("Name", text="Имя", anchor=W)
    tree.heading("Calories", text="калории", anchor=W)
    tree.heading("Proteins", text="Белки", anchor=W)
    tree.heading("fats", text="Жиры", anchor=W)
    tree.heading("carbohydrates", text="Углеводы", anchor=W)


    tree.column("#1", stretch=NO, width=745)
    tree.column("#2", stretch=NO, width=80)
    tree.column("#3", stretch=NO, width=80)
    tree.column("#4", stretch=NO, width=80)
    tree.column("#5", stretch=NO, width=80)

    for product in all_data:
        tree.insert("", END, values=product)
```

I hope there are people who can help solve this problem.

Comment: You should return your widgets from your functions and store them somewhere. Then you can reference them later when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class MainWin(tk.Tk)` works for me. In this case, the object
`self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=columns, show="headings")`
becomes available to other functions and all changes to it will be saved. This tested:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, BOTH, NO, END, W


class MainWin(tk.Tk):                      # Application Window Initialization
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()
        # Table init (to be initialized here instead of within the func)
        columns = ('Name', "Calories", "Proteins", "fats", "carbohydrates")
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=columns, show="headings")
        self.tree.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Open File BTN init
        self.open_file_btn = ttk.Button(self, text='Open File', command=self.open_file)
        self.open_file_btn.pack()
        self.open_file_btn.place(x=50, y=120)

        # Clear BTN init
        self.open_file_btn = ttk.Button(self, text='Clear Table', command=self.clear_table)
        self.open_file_btn.pack()
        self.open_file_btn.place(x=130, y=120)

    def clear_table(self):                  # Function to clear the table
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

    def open_file(self):                    # Function to react on button pressing
        self.show_data([1,2,3,4,5])

    def show_data(self, all_data):          # Function to reflect data in the table
        # columns = ('Name', "Calories", "Proteins", "fats", "carbohydrates")
        # self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=columns, show="headings")
        # self.tree.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.tree.heading("Name", text="Имя", anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading("Calories", text="калории", anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading("Proteins", text="Белки", anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading("fats", text="Жиры", anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading("carbohydrates", text="Углеводы", anchor=W)

        self.tree.column("#1", stretch=NO, width=745)
        self.tree.column("#2", stretch=NO, width=80)
        self.tree.column("#3", stretch=NO, width=80)
        self.tree.column("#4", stretch=NO, width=80)
        self.tree.column("#5", stretch=NO, width=80)

        for product in all_data:
            self.tree.insert("", END, values=product)


root = MainWin()
root.mainloop()
```

[Tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZQin.png)